# When 1 cell validates (IF condition), all other cells validate as well

Tags: excel

I have two columns with (1) DATE/TIME COMPLETED and (2) STATUS.
(1) has a formula of `=IF(B1="COMPLETED", NOW(), "")`

NOTE: I have changed the B1, B2, etc.. corresponding to the row number.

It means if the (2) STATUS is "COMPLETED", it should show the current date/time in column (1), else it should show blank.

But when I COMPLETED a cell, all other cell with COMPLETED status validate/refresh as well, which marks all with same date and time value.

How can I update only the status for the cell that is updated, without changing the other cells in STATUS as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit. It looks like a fairly decent question. You could improve it further by showing what you have tried; you can [edit] these attempts into your question. People here respond positively if you show effort, and it also means that people won't waste your time with things you've tried already. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't rely on `NOW()` in this case, whatsoever. Excel re-validates for a number of different reasons. You could either create a macro that gets the current time and sets it as *text*, or do the same thing manually.

Alternatively, to convert existing formulas to literal values, follow [this guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e). This should be done for each row immediately following the completion of the task, so that Excel doesn't have the opportunity to incorrectly re-evaluate it.

Comment: I have tried to convert it to text with TEXT(NOW(), "m/d/yy hh:mm") but still not working

Comment: @user6583346 I have updated the answer to include a method to convert formulas to literal text.

Answer (score 0):

now() gives you the current time as at the time of processing the formula. With it being a dynamic value, it will update everytime to the current date/time.

The only way I've found to be able to automate this is to use VBA (macros):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Assuming column 2 is actually columns "B". In case it's not, change target.column to the right column number
If Target.Column = 2 And UCase(Target.Text) = "COMPLETED" Then
    'Assuming the datetime field goes to the column to the left of the above column.
    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = Now
Else
    If Target.Column = 2 Then Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Clear
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this solves your issue.